# How to publish sitemap.xml file with webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack

I don't have much experience configuring Webpack and I am working on a React project and have created an external script that generates a `sitemap.xml` file. So far so good.

The project is using React 16 and Webpack 4.41, how can I make the `sitemap.xml` file available to be used in production? When I run `npm run build` locally I can see the file is not being added to the `/public` folder, even after I have added the xml rule ( module/rules ) to the webpack.config.js file.

```
mode: "production",
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, "./app"),
  entry: {
    app: "./js/app.js",
    styles: "./scss/main.scss",
  },
output: {
    filename: "[name].deploy.bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./public/assets"),
    publicPath: "/assets",
  },
module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.html/ },
      { test: /\.xml/ },
    ]
}
```

What Am I missing?

Can it be because my file is currently outside the context folder?

The (simplified) project structure is as follows:

```
project 
|  sitemap.xml
|  node-script-that-creates-sitemap.js
|  webpack.config.js
|
└───app/
|
└───public/
```

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution didn't have to do with webpack. I managed to solve the issue by copying the file in the build step.

I added these scripts to my `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {

"sitemap-to-build": "npm run generate-sitemap && cp ./sitemap.xml _site/sitemap.xml",

"build": "[other stuff...] && webpack --env.NODE_ENV=production --config webpack.config.js && npm run sitemap-to-build

}
```